# View ABI chromatogram plots with python

Tags: dna-sequencing, chromatography, biopython

I would like to view the chromatogram traces from a few ABI (.ab1) files. I would prefer to use python for this, or a function with python bindings, or at least some open source package such as EMBOSS.

If after viewing a plot I could also extract the plotted data in the form of an array, that would be a huge plus.

I have tried [the relevant Biopython parser](https://www.biostars.org/p/2464/), but it only returns a list of nucleotides (not th actual chromatogram). I have also tried abiview, but I get plots such as this, which makes absolutely no sense:

[image]

Could you help me out?

Comment: Is there anything that you want to do with the file that you can't already do with a free package such as Finch TV?

Comment: I think [this](http://www6.appliedbiosystems.com/support/software_community/ABIF_File_Format.pdf) might explain the .AB1 file format, which would be the first step toward writing your own file parser. If you can get the X and Y data out for each channel, you could plot it however you wanted. Good luck.

Comment: Have you looked at abiview from the package [EMBOSS](http://emboss.sourceforge.net/apps/release/6.6/emboss/apps/)? See this Biostars post: https://www.biostars.org/p/4097/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Biopython 1.65 ABI parser should expose the chromatogram data, as of Biopython 1.66 it should expose everything.

UPDATE: Example using this for plotting here: http://biopython.org/wiki/ABI_traces

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using Matlab, it does not read ab1 files directly, but it can if [Staden tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/staden/files/) are installed. The reason being is that the data is presented a lot better and there *is* documentation. I recently wrote a [QQC calculation script in Matlab](https://github.com/matteoferla/mutational_scanning) as proof of principle and I will rewrite it in python (due to server building) using it as a benchmark.

In Biopython the manual says:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
handle = open("myfile.ab1", "rb")
record=SeqIO.read(handle, "abi")
```

And that is where it stops. It does have the data. The trace data is stored as annotations:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(record.annotations, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Specifically, the actual raw data is:

```
print(record.annotations['abif_raw']['DATA9'])
print(record.annotations['abif_raw']['DATA10'])
print(record.annotations['abif_raw']['DATA11'])
print(record.annotations['abif_raw']['DATA12'])
```

but wait! The bases are not ATGC. but GATC as found here:

```
print(record.annotations['abif_raw']['FWO_1'])
```

Having played with `ab1` files in Matlab using the command:

```
[Sample, Probability] = scfread('temp_via_matlab.scf');
```

I know that there is not only raw data (Sample), but also probability data. The latter tells me where the peaks are (*e.g.* `Probability.peak_index(100)`) and how good they are. This will be very helpful. That data is saved here:

```
print('PLOC1 is peak_index in Matlab', record.annotations['abif_raw']['PLOC1']) # tuple of int
print('PBAS1 is what base it is', record.annotations['abif_raw']['PBAS1']) # str
```

Note that it is a wee bit different from MatLab and there are keys called PLOC2 and PBAS2 which have the same data as their 1 counterparts from what I can tell.
For a more detailed explanation of the many keys present see the [vignette for the R package sangerseqR](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/sangerseqR/inst/doc/sangerseq_walkthrough.pdf), which does the same and is annotated slightly better than biopython —although `scfread` in Matlab is a lot more neater (hence my recommendation).